# The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

> The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. {"exception":"[object] (League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException(code: 9)

I am experiencing this error when I'm refunding in a stripe app.

It says that the `token` has been revoked.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @hassanrazadev I guess not because I don't see any correct awnser!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this Exception as it is recommended in [this laracast discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-log-problems-when-using-laravel-passport-for-user-login-authentication?page=1#reply=389574).

Override and add below condition to `report()` method of `Handler` class.

\App\Exception\Handler

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException && $exception->getCode() == 9) {
        return;
    }
    parent::report($exception);
}
```